# How can I set up a workflow to run under a service account?

Tags: workflow, user-profile-service, active-directory

I am very new to SharePoint workflows, so please "[ELI5](https://www.reddit.com/r/explainlikeimfive/)" here.

I am trying to create a *Sharepoint 2010* workflow *using impersonation*.  I want to run that impersonation under a service account so that when I die/retire/quit the workflow will continue working, oblivious to my departure.

How do I do that?

**Edit**: added sharepoint version and reason for the service account (*italics*).

Comment: What kind of workflow? With SharePoint 2010 workflows you can use Impersonation which is effectively the same thing. Microsoft Flow can run under a designated account as well.

Comment: which SharePoint version you are using?

Comment: @Scott, is the issue resolved?

Answer (score 1):

Provide the service account the needful permission, lets say Full Control on the list. And publish the workflow with that service account.

Hope it will help.

Comment: _"publish the workflow with that service account"_  ... how?

Comment: Can u log in sp site ur Service account? if yes, just log in in ur SP Designer with this Service account. And after opening the workflow, just publish it again. That will do.

Comment: this won't provoke any change on the behavior of the workflow, the workflow still runs under the account of the person who tries to fire it : being the system account or the user making the change or calling the workflow, also is a horrible practice to manually login as a service execution account.

Comment: @Erin, The questioner asked about the "SharePoint 2010 workflow using impersonation" step.  
Now, SharePoint 2010 workflow works with System permission.
And for impersonation step (Only Available in SP 2010 Workflow) need Publisher's Permission to start.

Comment: the workflow impersonates the user that launches the workflow only in the impersonation step, not before launching it.  if the user never has access to the workflow they won't be able to launch it, also for the impersonation to work you require to add app permissions to the workflow service

Comment: @Erin, impersonation step can be added only in SharePoint 2010 Workflow. 
And add app permissions thing can be set for SharePoint 2013 workflow not for 2010.

Answer (score 0):

workflows run on the user account that is performing the changes to the list/library items.

even if you created the workflow, if userA creates a new item, the workflow will run under UserA,

the only reason you would need to execute the workflow under a service account is to elevate the user permissions, but it doesn't seems you need that

Short Answer: you don't need to make the workflow run under a service account in your case

---

Edit :

I think the problem is that you are the only user that can run or start the workflow, if that's the problem we need more feedback about what you are trying to accomplish, but if you are the only user that can run the workflow, then we need first to address that issue.

so a few questions here :

1.- is a site workflow or a list workflow
2.- how/when is the workflow launched

Comment: To add to this... A workflow (2013) can also contain an "App Step", which allows the workflow to run under a different ID, for example to modify data the user does not have access to. This is basically your "service account" Version. But for this to be possible, you need to grant the workflow the extra permissions first.

Comment: please see my edits.

Comment: added some questions to understand your problem a bit more